# Как организовывать поиск по базе

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем здравствуйте, есть DataGridView в которую я выгружаю данные из базы, 6000 строк, как можно сделать поиск по базе или по выгруженным строкам. Есть строка (textbox), пишем в строку например слово и в  DataGridView у нас подсвечивается строка, содержащие это слово. Строка в DataGridView содержит несколько колонок.  Как правильно организовать поиск по всем колонкам.

Comment: WinForms или WPF? Добавьте тег.

Comment: Искать нужно по одной колонке или одновременно по всем?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Подправил теги

Comment: Теперь важное уточнение: как данные попадают в грид? Напрямую или через привязку данных? С привязкой используется DataTable или типизированная коллекция? Какая именно коллекция?

Comment: Вариант с DataTable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46831632/5045688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать ICollectionView.
Для примера объявим какую-либо персону (пользователь, клиент...):

```
/// <summary>
/// Пользователь.
/// </summary>
public class Person
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Имя.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Возраст.
    /// </summary>
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Объявим нашу ViewModel:

```
public class MainVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainVM()
    {
        Items.Filter = PersonFilter;

        People.Add(new Person { Age = 18, Name = "Kate" });
        People.Add(new Person { Age = 31, Name = "John" });
        People.Add(new Person { Age = 12, Name = "Alex" });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Команда для начала сортировки.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand FindCommand => new DelegateCommand(() => Items.Refresh());

    /// <summary>
    /// Коллекция для отображения данных.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollectionView Items => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(People);

    /// <summary>
    /// Фильтр поиска по имени.
    /// </summary>
    public string FilterText { get; set; } = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// Коллекция для хранения данных.
    /// </summary>
    ObservableCollection<Person> People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Метод фильтрации.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool PersonFilter(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Person person))
            return false;

        return person.Name.ToLower().Contains(FilterText.ToLower());
    }
}
```

На окне сделаем примерно такую разметку:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Имя пользователя: "/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Width="200"/>

        <Button Content="Найти" 
                Command="{Binding FindCommand}"/>
    </WrapPanel>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              Grid.Row="1">

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

И получаем примерно такой вид поиска:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, про WPF я знаю, что с помощью этого способа можно так делать.

Comment: Нужно было изначально указать, что используете не WPF, чтож, удачи в поисках решения.

Comment: У вас отличный ответ,я скоро буду делать тоже самое на wpf. Но в wpf легче это сделать

Comment: Удачи в решении